# Bigquery within nested reaptable record, find other values that occur most with given value

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider the example `personsDataSchema` given on in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#within)

```
                |- fullName: string (required)
                |- age: integer
                |- gender: string
                +- phoneNumber: record
                |  |- areaCode: integer
                |  |- number: integer
                +- children: record (repeated)
                |  |- name: string
                |  |- gender: string
                |  |- age: integer
                +- citiesLived: record (repeated)
                |  |- place: string
                |  +- yearsLived: integer (repeated)
```

Here the `CitiesLived` is a repeatable record. so a single person can live in multiple cities.
Now, 
I want to find out what are the most other most popular cities for persons living in `CitiesLives.place` `X`. Is there is a way by which I can get count of other cities `WITHIN RECORD` of place `X`?

As per the docs,
It seems its possible to get the count of values within a record

`SELECT
  fullName,
  COUNT(children.name) WITHIN RECORD AS numberOfChildren
FROM [dataset.tableId];`

so wondering if its possible to use this `WITHIN RECORD` to  find other values that occur most with given value?

Hopefully, this makes sense. if not, then let me know. I will add the missing details.

Comment: I don't understand what does "what are the most other most popular cities for persons living in CitiesLives.place X". Maybe you can give a simple example ?

Comment: example what are the other popular cities among people to lived in Dublin. so for that, I am thinking I should select persons who have lived in more than one city & try to find sister cities to Dublin where people who lived in Dublin have have also lived. so trying to find the best combination here. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using example from comments , the query below will show 10 most popular cities among people who lived in Dublin

```
SELECT TOP(citiesLived.place, 10), COUNT(*) FROM
Persons
OMIT RECORD IF EVERY(citiesLived.place != "Dublin")
```

Note, that this query will also include Dublin itself, but it is easy to remove it if needed.